# Strange Windows Server 2008 R2 (FTP Server) Error - Caused by a specific combination of characters in the filename of uploaded file

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ftp

We are running Windows Server 2008 R2, which is setup to be a FTP server.

Everything seemed to be working fine until one our our cilents started complaining about their uploads being halted with the message "Connection with server reset".  Further diagnosis revealed that a specific combination of characters in the filename will cause a repeatable error.  I am hoping that a form expert can confirm the error or perhaps provide a solution.

This is an example filename that will always cause the error: REPORT_FILED_000000001 (extension does not matter)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  We need files named like this to work properly with our FTP server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were able to get rid of the problem by enabling server to server transfers/FXP.